# I want to use php to display a webpage on another web page.

Tags: php

Have found some code that works but it also displays the code on my page. Other options display complete HTML source code. At the moment, my code is

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('widget.html');
echo "$contents";
?>
```

and it displays like this: http://www.tarantulaweb.co.za/SiyabongaAfrica/foodbank-reaches-22500-people.php (right hand column)

Comment: Use `require()`?

Answer (score 1):

take out echo

```
<?php
file_get_contents('widget.html');
?>
```

Comment: If I do this, nothing displays.

Comment: can you modifi the function?

Comment: can you modify the function file_get_contents() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use print instead of echo may it helps you
or
You can use iframe tag like,